# Get Voucher when you enter email address on a page

Tags: email, discount, coupon-codes, customer-session

I want to give **voucher code** if user enters **email address**

- soon as they **enter the email** (Discount should be showed in page)
- I want to set **cart rule** for the voucher

Is this possible?